# Running PHPUnit TestCase( not the framework native) on Yii2

Tags: yii2, phpunit, yii2-advanced-app

I am trying to run `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` on `Yii2-advanced`. Installed it via composer in folder `PHPUnit` in the root directory. From there I tried to test with simple test but what I get is an error:

```
 phpunit TestLogin.php
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'dektrium\user\models\LoginForm' not found in Z:\toma\toma-metropizza\htdocs\frontend\models\LoginForm.php on line 8

Fatal error: Class 'dektrium\user\models\LoginForm' not found in Z:\toma\toma-metropizza\htdocs\frontend\models\LoginForm.php on line 8
```

This my `TestLogin.php` file from the `PHPUnit` directroy:

```
<?php

require_once "vendor/autoload.php";
require_once "../frontend/models/LoginForm.php";

class TestLogin extends PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
{
    public function setUp()
    {
        $login =  new LoginForm();
    }

    public function testStatic()
    {
        $this->assertClassHasStaticAttribute('test', 'LoginForm');
    }
}
```

This is my `LoginForm.php`:

```
<?php 

namespace frontend\models;

use Yii;
use \dektrium\user\models\LoginForm as BaseLoginForm;

class LoginForm extends BaseLoginForm
{
    public static $test = [];

    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'login'      => Yii::$app->OutData->getLabel(208),
            'password'   => Yii::$app->OutData->getLabel(98),
            'rememberMe' => Yii::t('app','app.Remember me'),
        ];
    }
}
```

It extends the base dektrium user model. But it seems like the test can't find the base model or something. Can you give me advice? I don't want to use the Yii2 build in tests. Want to write my own. Thank you in advance!

**EDIT** Directroy structure:

```
app/
   /frontned
      /models
         LoginForm.php
   /PHPUnit
      /vendor
      composer.json
      conposer.lock
      TestLogin.php
   /vendor 
   etc.
```

Comment: What is your directory structure? Maybe your `require_once "../frontend/models/LoginForm.php";` doesn't work properly? BTW, it's wierd seeing requiring anything but autoload. I recommend to learn [composer autoload docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload). And there is phpunits `--bootstrap` option, which can be used like `phpunit --bootstrap vendor/autoload.php` so there is no need for any `require_once` in your class files

Comment: Edited the directory. Take a look above. After executing the `--bootstrap` command, I get this: `Cannot open file "vendor/autoload.php".` Tried to execute it from PHPUnit folder. After executing without requiring manually the `LoginForm.php` class : `Error: Class 'LoginForm' not found
Z:\toma\toma-metropizza\htdocs\PHPUnit\TestLogin.php:9
` If I copy `LoginForm.php` in the `PHPUnit` directory it works fine :/ But it is not ok to copy every model, right ? :D

Comment: Have you run `composer install`?

Comment: I added the package line to the composer file and then ran `composer update`. Isn't it the same ? Or I am in some BIG mistake :/